# How to create a `FnOnce` function

Tags: functional-programming, rust, traits

I am trying to create a function that is only a `FnOnce`.

The following snippet of code do not work:

```
// Attempt 1
//  Error doesn't have a size known at compile-time
let f: FnOnce() -> () = || println!("Hello");

// Attempt 2
fn g<T: FnOnce() -> ()>(c: T) -> (FnOnce() -> ()) {
    c
}
// Error: doesn't have a size known at compile-time
let f = g(|| println!("Hello"));

// Attempt 3
// Error: cast to unsized type
let f = (|| println!("Hello")) as (FnOnce() -> ());
```

Comment: `FnOnce() -> ()` isn't a type, it's a trait. What's wrong with `let f = || println!("Hello");`?

Comment: That's fine, I am just trying to understand how Fn* traits work.

Comment: @fcracker79 this is more related to anonymous types of closures than to the Fn traits

Answer (score 1):

`FnOnce` is a trait for closures which can only be called once, typically because the captured values are moved into the closure, and they are consumed during the call. For example, we can capture a value and move it out as a return value:

```
fn delay<A: 'static>(a: A) -> Box<dyn FnOnce() -> A> {
    Box::new(move || a)
}

fn main() {
    let a = "hello".to_string();
    let f = delay(a);
    println!("{}", f());
}
```

Note that the `move` keyword is not strictly necessary. The compiler sees that `a` needs to be moved into the closure, in order to be returned as a value and moved out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, I expected to have the same result as with `let f = move || println!("{}", a)`: since I am moving `a` in the closure environment, why isn't `f` an `FnOnce`?

Comment: @fcracker79 `println!` is a macro that does a lot of magic. So when `a` appears as an argument without `&` that doesn't mean it is moved.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Agreed, but the `move` keyword should do the trick. The `println!` should be unrelevant from that point of view.
All in all, is there a way to let Rust decide to create a closure that is *only* a `FnOnce`, without requiring tricks such as functions that take a `FnOnce` as an argument?